# RemoteAuthenticationHandler state and code_challenge verification

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I have created RemoteAuthenticationHandler, which looks like that:

```
public class AuthAndAuthHandler : RemoteAuthenticationHandler<AuthAndAuthSchemeOptions>

{
    public AuthAndAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthAndAuthSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

        var state = new byte[128];
        var nonce = new byte[128];
        var codeVerifier = new byte[64];

        rng.GetBytes(state);
        rng.GetBytes(nonce);
        rng.GetBytes(codeVerifier);

        var codeChallenge = SHA256.HashData(codeVerifier);

        Response.Cookies.Append("Nonce", Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.HashData(nonce)), new CookieOptions
        {
            Path = "/callback",
            HttpOnly = true,
            IsEssential = true,
            Secure = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            Expires = Clock.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
        });

        Response.Redirect($"{Options.Authority}/authorization?client_id={Options.ClientId}" +
            $"&callback_uri={Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Options.CallbackPath}&scopes={Options.Scopes}" +
            $"&state={Convert.ToBase64String(state)}&nonce={Convert.ToBase64String(nonce)}&code_challenge={Convert.ToBase64String(codeChallenge)}");
    }

    protected override async Task<HandleRequestResult> HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in `HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()` method I have to verify state, which I will get after successful remote authorization. How can I do this, when after Challenge I'm losing earlier generated state and code verifier?

Comment: Could you share more codes?HandleChallengeAsync method is used to deal with 401 challenge concerns,why you  authenticated successfully and got into this method?

Comment: Perhaps I expressed myself vaguely. The assumption is that after receiving 401, I call `HandleChallengeAsync`. If the user logs in after redirecting him to /authorization, he should be redirected to /callback, where the `HandleRemoteAuthenticationAsync` method will be called. And now I don't know how to verify the state parameter, which I will get as a query parameter dla w /callback, because I no longer have access to the state I created in `HandleChallengeAsync`. Maybe my way is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **state**, you can validate it with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISecureDataFormat<TData>`. It can be defined as property inside your custom options (pseudocode):

```
public class CustomRemoteOptions : RemoteAuthenticationOptions
{
    public CustomRemoteOptions()
    {
        var dataProtector = DataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(
            typeof(CustomRemoteHandler).FullName);
        StateDataFormat = new PropertiesDataFormat(dataProtector);
    }

    internal ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties> StateDataFormat { get; }
}
```

Then use it inside `CustomRemoteHandler`:

```
public class CustomRemoteHandler : RemoteAuthenticationHandler<CustomRemoteOptions>
{
    protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        string state = Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(properties);
        // Then add the state to the URI.
    }
    
    protected override async Task<HandleRequestResult> HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var state = Request.Query["state"];
    
        var properties = Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(state);
        if (properties == null)
        {
            return HandleRequestResult.Fail("The Custom authentication state was missing or invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** if you also need to validate correlation id, then add `GenerateCorrelationId(properties);` inside `HandleChallengeAsync` and the following lines inside `HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync`:

```
if (!ValidateCorrelationId(properties))
{
    return HandleRequestResult.Fail("Validation of correlation failed.", properties);
}
```

**Note**: to make the code testable you can move initialization of `StateDataFormat` to custom `IPostConfigureOptions` implementation.